# Netifly Fails To Load Ressource After Deployment

Tags: reactjs, git, github, netlify, netlify-cms

I've deployed a React website on Netifly this morning from a github repository.

I then made a few changes, pushed them to github, and triggered a new deployment on Netifly. Now the website is a blank page. In the console, I have the message:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

So I've created a new project on Netifly, with the same repository. The issue remains. Is it a temporary issue from Netifly? If not, how could I fix that?

Answer (score 7):

In a create react app, a typical error would be to set the `homepage` to be an absolute path when you might have wanted a relative path to the `index.html`

Try using the relative path for now, then change based on your needs.

In `package.json`

```
"homepage": ".",
```

This will set the relative path of the create react app to be where the `index.html` is located.

***Note:*** Note: this feature is available with react-scripts@0.9.0 and higher.

You can [read more about setting relative paths here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#building-for-relative-paths)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message after commiting `vue.config.js` file. Deleting this file fixed my problem.

Comment: In Vue - only deleting the vue.config.js file, as you suggested, worked for me. I did not need to edit my package.json file. Thanks!